# The limit of the product $\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1 - (2i + 1)a/(2n)}{1 - ia/n}$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

Given that $0 < a < 1$, what is the value of
$$ P = \lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1 - (2i + 1)a/(2n)}{1 - ia/n} $$
Thus, $P_n$, the $n$th term, is
$$ P_n = \frac{1-3a/2n}{1-a/n}\cdot \frac{1-5a/2n}{1-2a/n}\cdots \frac{1-(2n+1)a/2n}{1-a} $$

---

#### Motivation

The product describes a real-live physical problem. Put simply, if you have a river or stream in which you're sampling at an upstream site A and a downstream site B and you analyze the chemistry of the stream at A and B, if the concentration has changed, it is because of ground water which has seeped in between A and B. By making some simplifying assumptions, the concentration and amount of ground water which has entered are calculated using the evaluation of this infinite product.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was the motivation behind this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry it's taken me so long to answer your question -- the motivation is quite exciting (to me): it describes a real-live physical problem. Put simply, if you have a river or stream in which you're sampling at an upstream site A and a downstream site B and you analyze the chemistry of the stream at A and B, if the concentration has changed, it is because of ground water which has seeped in between A and B. By making some simplifying assumptions, the concentration and amount of ground water which has entered are calculated using the evaluation of this infinite product. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool, that's excellent!  BTW please remember to accept a solution it was useful to you.  Thanks.

Comment: If you will provide me with your affiliation (or how you'd like to be referred to), I will be happy to acknowledge you when these results are published.

Answer (score 15):

Take logs of both sides to get

$$\log{P_n} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\log{\left [ 1- a\frac{i}{n} - \frac{a}{2 n}\right]} -\log{\left [ 1- a\frac{i}{n}\right]} \right) $$

Noting that $n$ is large, so we can rewrite the summand as

$$\log{\left [ 1- a\frac{i}{n} - \frac{a}{2 n}\right]} -\log{\left [ 1- a\frac{i}{n}\right]} = \log{\left( 1-\frac{a/(2 n)}{1-a i/n}\right)} \sim -\frac{a}{2} \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{1-a i/n} $$

In the limit as $n \to \infty$, this is a Riemann sum and becomes the integral

$$\log{P} = -\frac{a}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1-a x} = \frac12 \log{(1-a)}$$

Therefore

$$P=\sqrt{1-a}$$

**BONUS**

Here are a few plots of log base $2$ of the relative error between the above result $P$ and the finite product $P_n$ vs $\log_2{n}$.  The values of $a$ from left to right are $1/4$, $1/3$, $2/3$, $9/10$, and $99/100$.

[image]

**EDIT**

@Did has pointed out that the step in the second line needs more justification, i.e., a quantification of the error term inherent in the $\sim$ symbol.  Along these lines, for sufficiently large $n$, we may write

$$\log{\left( 1-\frac{a/(2 n)}{1-a i/n}\right)} = -\frac{a}{2} \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{1-a i/n} + \frac12 \left ( \frac{a}{2} \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{1-a i/n} \right )^2 + \cdots$$

As we did for the first term on the RHS, we may also sum over $i$ for the subsequent terms.  For example, the first error term has behavior, for large $n$

$$\frac{a^2}{8 n}\; \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{(1-a i/n)^2} $$

which, in the limit as $n\to\infty$, is another Riemann sum; the term therefore behaves as

$$\frac{a^2}{8(1-a)} \frac1n$$

It should be clear that higher order terms in the log behave as higher orders of $1/n$.  Thus, the error terms arranged in this way do not contribute to the sum for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Perhaps I am not following your work, but your first line appears to have a mistake: you have log(1-i/n-a/2n) and it should be log(1-ia/n-a/2n). Also on the first line, you have log(1-i/n) and it should be log(1-ia/n). Is it possible all of this washes out in the end? -- Your final answer appears to be "computationally" correct for a = 0.5.

Comment: @RonaldAntweiler: What you point to was a typo - look at the edited version, it is correct.

Comment: I agree: nice answer

Comment: The argument that $n$ is large fails because $i$ can be large too. It seems this step of the proof should be expanded.

Comment: @Did: maybe I am missing something, but since $0<a<1$, $0 < a i/n < 1$ as well.  Thus, even when $i=n$, one can always find some $n$ sufficiently large such that the above expansions are true.  But maybe you are seeing something else that I am not.

Comment: You are approximating $\log(1-ai/n)$ uniformly by $-ai/n$. This is not true for $i$ in $[1..n]$, for example, if $i=n/2$ and $a=1/2$, say, then $\log(3/4)\ne-1/4$. Re your comment, if $i=n$, then $\log(1-ai/n)=\log(1-a)$ and $-ai/n=-a$ hence their difference is nonzero and non vanishing when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Did: I don't think I am doing that.  Rather, I am saying that $$\log{\left( 1-\frac{a/(2 n)}{1-a i/n}\right)} \sim -\frac{a}{2} \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{1-a i/n} $$  This holds for sufficiently large $n$.  If I were doing the approximation you stated, then I would have that this approximation would behave as $-a/(2 n)$ which is indeed wrong.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\sim$ here?

Comment: @did: fair question and I admit to being informal here.  I meant that the $log$ term may be replaced by the $a/(2 n)$... piece for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Of course this is what you meant *informally*. But mathematically, how does this translate? Uniformly on $i$ when $n\to\infty$? With what kind of error term (to be summed over $i$...)?

Comment: @did: if you take the next term in the log and sum over $i$, you get an error term $$\frac{a^2}{4 (1-a)} \frac1{n}$$ resulting from another Riemann sum.

Comment: Can you make this heuristics explicit?

Comment: @did: I added a bit to the answer.

Comment: Right. I guess the more precise heuristics you added can be made into a full proof.

Comment: @did: thanks for pushing me to improve the post.

Comment: My pleasure... :-)

Answer (score 4):

The product can be rewritten as
$$\mathcal{P}_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1 - (2i + 1)a/(2n)}{1 - ia/n}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\frac{n}{a}-\frac12-i}{\frac{n}{a}-i}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{a}-n\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{a}\right)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{a}-\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{a}-n-\frac12\right)}$$
Now taking the logarithm and using Stirling formula 
$$\ln\Gamma(x)=x(\ln x-1)+\frac12(\ln2\pi-\ln x)+O\left(x^{-1}\right)\qquad \text{as}\;
x\rightarrow\infty, $$
we arrive at 
$$\ln\mathcal{P}_{\infty}=\frac12\ln(1-a),$$
which reproduces Ron Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{P\equiv\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\prod_{i = 1}^{n}
     {1 - \pars{2i + 1}a/\pars{2n} \over 1 - ia/n}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\ln\pars{1 - \pars{2i + 1}a/\pars{2n} \over 1 - ia/n}}
> =\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\int_{1 - ia/n}^{1 - \pars{2i + 1}a/\pars{2n}}{\dd x \over x}
> \end{align}

Set$\ds{\quad x = 1 - {a \over n}\,i - {a \over 2n}\,t}$:

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\ln\pars{1 - \pars{2i + 1}a/\pars{2n} \over 1 - ia/n}}
> =\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}
> {-a\,\dd t/\pars{2n} \over 1 - \pars{a/n}\,i - at/\pars{2n}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}
> {1 \over -n/a + i + t/2}\,\dd t
> =\half\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}
> \pars{{1 \over i - n/a +  t/2} - {1 \over i + n - n/a +  t/2}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}
> \pars{{1 \over i - n/a +  t/2} - {1 \over i + n - n/a +  t/2}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\half\,n\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}
> {1 \over \pars{i + 1 - n/a +  t/2}\pars{i + 1 + n - n/a +  t/2}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
> \Psi\pars{1 + n - {n \over a} +  {t \over 2}}
> -\Psi\pars{1 - {n \over a} +  {t \over 2}}}\,\dd t
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\ln\pars{1 - \pars{2i + 1}a/\pars{2n} \over 1 - ia/n}}
=\half\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
\ln\pars{n - {n \over a}} - \ln\pars{-\,{n \over a}}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\half\,\ln\pars{1 - a}=\ln\pars{\root{1 - a}}
\end{align}

> $$P\equiv\color{#66f}{\large\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\prod_{i = 1}^{n}
> {1 - \pars{2i + 1}a/\pars{2n} \over 1 - ia/n}}
> =\exp\pars{\ln\pars{\root{1 - a}}}\color{#66f}=\color{#66f}{\large\root{1 - a}}
> $$